# I want to know the expiration date of the Twitter access token acquired with use Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I use Firebase Authentication to authenticate with Twitter.

I would like to post to Twitter using the access token obtained when I authenticated with "signin ()" below.

How long is this access token valid?

I did not understand it even after checking it, so I will ask you here.

Thank you.

```
private var provider: OAuthProvider?

init() {
    provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")
}

func signin() {
    provider?.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
        guard let credential = credential, error == nil else {
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            let credential = result?.credential as! OAuthCredential
                let accessToken = credential.accessToken
                let accessTokenSecret = credential.secret
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credentials in Firebase do not 'expire' per se. Once a user signs in according to the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), a user's token will only expire when:

> - The user is deleted
> - The user is disabled
> - A major account change is    detected for the user. This includes events like password or email    address updates.

So, you should not sign a user in every time the app opens. You only need to sign in once, then whenever the app opens up the user will still be signed in.

Comment: The question is asking specifically about the twitter credientials that come from a Firebase auth sign-in.  Both Firebase and Twiter credentials will expire if not refreshed.  The question is asking how long the twitter credential lasts without requiring a refresh.

Comment: "Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived. Every time a user signs in, the user credentials are sent to the Firebase Authentication backend and exchanged for a Firebase ID token (a JWT) and refresh token. Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens. Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:

The user is deleted
The user is disabled
A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates."

Comment: And does that apply to the twitter token specifically? We're not talking about sessions, we're talking about credentials that expire for security reasons.

Comment: It applies to all authentication methods on Firebase. The credentials are used to get the Firebase ID token and a refresh token, and then every time the app loads up the refresh token does as the name implies, it refreshes the Firebase ID token.

Comment: But the question is asking about a twitter token, for use with calling twitter APIs.  It stands to reason that if you just hold that token, it will expire.  The values in it won't refresh themselves.  What do you do to handle this case?  Presumably one would need to get a new token.